# X-Pack & Logstash - No output to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat, xpack

I have an installation of **X-Pack, Elasticsearch & Logstash**. Logstash is alreay reporting to elasticsearch for the monitoring part of X-Pack.

---

Now I want logstash to pass through any beat that comes to the pipe to elasticsearch.

---

I followed this guide [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/logstash.html) and created the mentioned user & role.
I additionally created a role for each beat type that has the mentioned privileges and assigned the roles to the same user, (e.g. one for `filebeat-*`), using the information from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/beats.html).

My `logstash.conf`looks the following:

```
input {
  beats {
   port => 5044
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
   index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
   document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
   user => "user"
   password => "pass-word"
 }
  file {
   path => "C:\temp\%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}.log"
 }
}
```

I am getting files created (e.g. for `filebeat`) but the indices in elasticsearch are **not created** and no data appears in elasticsearch.

Does anyone see if there is something wrong in the configuration? I am struggling since hours to find an error/solution.

Publishing beats directly to elasticsearch (without Logstash) using the mentioned user is working (e.g. using `metricbeat`).

Also I do not see something strange in the log, simply the output to elastic is missing:

> 07:52:53.807 [[main]>worker0] DEBUG logstash.pipeline - filter received {"event"=>{...}}
>   07:52:53.807 [[main]>worker0] DEBUG logstash.pipeline - filter received {"event"=>{...}}
>   07:52:53.807 [[main]>worker0] DEBUG logstash.pipeline - output received {"event"=>{...}}
>   07:52:53.807 [[main]>worker0] DEBUG logstash.pipeline - output received {"event"=>{...}}
>   07:52:53.870 [[main]>worker0] DEBUG logstash.outputs.file - File, writing event to file. {:filename=>"C:/temp/filebeat-2017.04.11.log"}
>   07:52:53.870 [[main]>worker0] DEBUG logstash.outputs.file - File, writing event to file. {:filename=>"C:/temp/filebeat-2017.04.11.log"}
>   07:52:53.870 [[main]>worker0] INFO  logstash.outputs.file - Opening file {:path=>"C:/temp/filebeat-2017.04.11.log"}
>   07:52:53.870 [[main]>worker0] DEBUG logstash.outputs.file - Starting stale files cleanup cycle {:files=>{"C:/temp/filebeat-2017.04.11.log"=>#>}}
>   07:52:53.870 [[main]>worker0] DEBUG logstash.outputs.file - 0 stale files found {:inactive_files=>{}}

---

Thank you already!

---

**UPDATE:**

If I change the password, I get the following error in the logstash log:

> 08:22:33.877 [[main]>worker1] ERROR logstash.outputs.elasticsearch - Got a bad response code from server, but this code is not considered retryable. Request will be dropped {:code=>401, :response_body=>"{\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"security_exception\",\"reason\":\"unable to authenticate user [beat] for REST request [/_bulk]\",\"header\":{\"WWW-Authenticate\":\"Basic realm=\\"security\\" charset=\\"UTF-8\\"\"}}],\"type\":\"security_exception\",\"reason\":\"unable to authenticate user [beat] for REST request [/_bulk]\",\"header\":{\"WWW-Authenticate\":\"Basic realm=\\"security\\" charset=\\"UTF-8\\"\"}},\"status\":401}", :request_body=>"{\"index\":{\"_id\":null,\"_index\"

So it seems to be actually communicating with elasticsearch, but the index does not get created. Unfortunately I have no statement in the elasticsearch log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer on my own, for those struggling with a similar problem:

I had some weird settings in my `elasticsearch.yml` regarding `action.auto_create_index` that prevented the index from being created.

This became visible after changing the log level of elasticsearch to `debug` the way it was mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-logging-secrets).

As those were not needed I removed them and now everything works as expected.

Comment: If you installed X-Pack, you can still use hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"] not the https?